# Setting both spatial extent and resolution when using gdalwarp?

Tags: gdalwarp, modis, resolution

I would like to overlay two tiff image that orginally have different projections. One is MODIS sinusoidal and the other one is WGS84. I use gdalwarp to re-project the latter into the same projection as the former. After that the two images matches in size but there is still some shift. 
The gdalwarp command I used is :

gdalwarp -t_srs modis.prj -tr 463.312716 -463.312716 in.tif out.tif
modis.prj contains the WKT that configures the target projection.

I think the mismtach is becasue the spatial extent (i.e., origin) between the two data does not match perfectly. I know using -te xmin ymin xmax ymax in gdalwarp can set the spatial extent. My confusion is that I think given the resolution, only one pair of (xmax,ymax) or (xmin,ymin) should be needed, no ?

My hope is after setting exactly the (xmax,ymax) in gdalwarp as the former data set, with exactly the same resolution and the same projection system, then these two data sets should perfectly match.

Does anyone have any comments/suggestions?

[image]